# Prove that an equation has solution in R

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$,  $x\in\mathbb R$  and

$$f(x^2 + 3x + 1) = f^2(x) + 3f(x) + 1.$$

Prove that $f(x)=x$ has a solution $\in \mathbb R.$

Comment: I don't get the point. If $f(x)=x$ then the statement is that $x^2 + 3x + 1 = x^2 + 3x + 1$ has a solution.

Comment: It is always good to give some background on your question. What have you tried, where did you get stuck? In a few minutes somebody will just tell you the answer, but you missed an opportunity to learn problem solving strategy.

Comment: That's the whole question, I can't figure out how to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $y$ be a solution to $x=x^2+3x+1$, then you get a quadratic equation in $f(y)$ which you can solve for $f(y)$.

Comment: The solution to x = x^2 + 3x + 1 is -1. That makes y = -1. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @AQUATH Yes that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

$y^2+3y+1=y$ 
$y^2+2y+1$ 
$y = -1$

$f(y)=f^2(y)+3f(y)+1$ 
$f^2(y)+2f(y)+1=0$ 
$(f(y)+1)^2=0$ 
$f(y)=-1$

Therefore $f(x)=x$ has a solution $x=-1\in \mathbb{R}$